# Setting a debug function from the command line in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a namespace like this:

```
(ns foo.core)

(def ^:dynamic *debug-fn*
  "A function taking arguments [bar baz]"
  nil)

(defn bar-info
  [bar _]
  (println bar))

(defn baz-info
  [_ baz]
  (println baz))

(defn do-stuff
  [bar baz]
  (when *debug-fn* (*debug-fn* bar baz)))

(defn -main
  [& {:keys [debug-fn]}]
  (binding [*debug-fn* (symbol debug-fn)]  ;; THIS WON'T WORK!
    (do-stuff 27 42)))
```

What I would like to do is allow a debug function to be specified from the command line like this: `lein run bar-info` or `lein run baz-info`.

I'm not sure how to take the string specified as a command-line argument and turn it into the namespace-qualified function to bind. Do I need a macro to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [ns-resolve](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/ns-resolve), you will need to specify namespace where your function is defined though.

```
user=> (defn f [n] (* n n n))
#'user/f
user=> ((ns-resolve *ns* (symbol "f")) 10)
1000
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `alter-var-root`:

```
user=> (doc alter-var-root)
-------------------------
clojure.core/alter-var-root
([v f & args])
  Atomically alters the root binding of var v by applying f to its
  current value plus any args
nil
user=> (alter-var-root #'*debug-fn* (fn [v] (fn [x] (println x) x)))
#<user$eval171$fn__172$fn__173 user$eval171$fn__172$fn__173@7c93d88e>
user=> (*debug-fn* 1)
1
1
```

Comment: I think problem is not with the binding but with the translation from string to callable function

Comment: O yes, I see it now. Sorry :)

Comment: Well, there was also a problem with the binding, due to my real `do-stuff` function creating a Swing panel with some callbacks, thus defeating my good intentions with `binding`. So thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

Though I've accepted [Guillermo's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22095994/58994), I figured that it might also be useful to add the solution I ended up going with:

```
(def debug-fns
  {:bar-info (fn [bar _] (println bar))
   :baz-info (fn [_ baz] (println baz))

(def active-debug-fns (atom []))

(defn activate-debug-fn!
  [fn-key]
  (let [f (debug-fns fn-key)]
    (if f
      (swap! active-debug-fns conj f)
      (warn (str "Debug function " fn-key " not found! Available functions are: "
                 (join " " (map name (keys debug-fns))))))))

(defn debug-fn-keys
  [args]
  (if (args "--debug")
    (split (or (args "--debug") "") #",")
    []))

(defn do-stuff
  [bar baz]
  (doseq [f @active-debug-fns]
    (f bar baz)))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (let [args (apply hash-map args)]
    (doseq [f (debug-fn-keys args)]
      (activate-debug-fn! (keyword k)))
    (do-stuff 27 42)))
```

So now you can say something like `lein run --debug bar-info` to get info on bars, or `lein run --debug bar,baz` to get info on both bars and bazes.

Any suggestions to make this more idiomatic will be happily accepted and edited in. :)